# vb.net retrieving information from access to list box

Tags: vb.net

Am using MS Access as my back end and I am having a table called "Dept" with 2 columns (dename & cname). In Vb.Net when I click a command button, all the data's of the first column should be displayed in ListBox1 and the Second column in ListBox2. I do not know how to proceed, Can any one help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why not do something like this.

```
dim data as datatable = (function to retrive information)

Listbox1.datasource = data
Listbox.DataTextField = "ColumnName1"
Listbox1.databind()

Listbox2.datasource = data
ListBox2.DataTextField = "ColumnName2"
Listbox2.databind()
```